# Fatal error: SIGSEGV everytime I launch Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, java-11

When I try to launch android studio, I have this error :

```
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f69987bd512, pid=9119, tid=9160
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.10) (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.10+0-b96-7249189, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x457512]  metaspace::BlockFreelist::get_block(unsigned long)+0x1a2
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P %E" (or dumping to /home/tiany/core.9119)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /root/java_error_in_studio_9119.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Can anyone help me please?
PS: Im' using openJDK11 on Ubuntu 20.04.2 lts and it gives the same error sometimes when I try to compile a Java code.
Thanks in advance

```
---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -Xms256m -Xmx1280m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Didea.vendor.name=Google -Dsun.tools.attach.tmp.only=true -XX:ErrorFile=/root/java_error_in_studio_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=/root/java_error_in_studio_.hprof -Didea.vendor.name=Google -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2020.3 -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio64.vmoptions -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.jre.check=true com.intellij.idea.Main

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 520  @ 2.40GHz, 4 cores, 3G, Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Time: Mon Sep 27 12:35:42 2021 MDT elapsed time: 3.271945 seconds (0d 0h 0m 3s)
```

```
Current thread (0x000000000261e800):  JavaThread "ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6" [_thread_in_vm, id=9160, stack(0x00007f68fc023000,0x00007f68fc124000)]

Stack: [0x00007f68fc023000,0x00007f68fc124000],  sp=0x00007f68fc11f4b0,  free space=1009k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x457512]  metaspace::BlockFreelist::get_block(unsigned long)+0x1a2
V  [libjvm.so+0xb379aa]  metaspace::SpaceManager::allocate(unsigned long)+0x8a
V  [libjvm.so+0xa1ab75]  Metaspace::allocate(ClassLoaderData*, unsigned long, MetaspaceObj::Type, Thread*)+0x75
V  [libjvm.so+0x5e40c7]  ConstantPool::allocate(ClassLoaderData*, int, Thread*)+0x87
V  [libjvm.so+0x5570c5]  ClassFileParser::parse_stream(ClassFileStream const*, Thread*)+0x575
V  [libjvm.so+0x556b10]  ClassFileParser::ClassFileParser(ClassFileStream*, Symbol*, ClassLoaderData*, Handle, InstanceKlass const*, GrowableArray<Handle>*, ClassFileParser::Publicity, Thread*)+0x290
V  [libjvm.so+0x8fce74]  KlassFactory::create_from_stream(ClassFileStream*, Symbol*, ClassLoaderData*, Handle, InstanceKlass const*, GrowableArray<Handle>*, Thread*)+0xb4
V  [libjvm.so+0xb9bfc1]  SystemDictionary::resolve_from_stream(Symbol*, Handle, Handle, ClassFileStream*, Thread*)+0x221
V  [libjvm.so+0x802567]  jvm_define_class_common(JNIEnv_*, char const*, _jobject*, signed char const*, int, _jobject*, char const*, Thread*)+0x2f7
V  [libjvm.so+0x80272b]  JVM_DefineClassWithSource+0x11b
C  [libjava.so+0xcd4e]  Java_java_lang_ClassLoader_defineClass1+0x1be
J 1391  java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/security/ProtectionDomain;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; java.base@11.0.10 (0 bytes) @ 0x00007f697ffdf0ea [0x00007f697ffdefc0+0x000000000000012a]
J 2368 c1 java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/security/ProtectionDomain;)Ljava/lang/Class; java.base@11.0.10 (43 bytes) @ 0x00007f6970686f24 [0x00007f6970686e00+0x0000000000000124]
J 1913 c1 com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[B)Ljava/lang/Class; (10 bytes) @ 0x00007f69705baaac [0x00007f69705baa40+0x000000000000006c]
J 2449 c1 com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/intellij/util/lang/Resource;)Ljava/lang/Class; (148 bytes) @ 0x00007f69706b7374 [0x00007f69706b7020+0x0000000000000354]
J 1895 c1 com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._findClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; (59 bytes) @ 0x00007f69705b5594 [0x00007f69705b5340+0x0000000000000254]
J 1894 c1 com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; (21 bytes) @ 0x00007f69705b4ec4 [0x00007f69705b4e60+0x0000000000000064]
J 1112 c1 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class; java.base@11.0.10 (122 bytes) @ 0x00007f6970439b2c [0x00007f6970439880+0x00000000000002ac]
J 755 c1 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; java.base@11.0.10 (7 bytes) @ 0x00007f697036353c [0x00007f6970363440+0x00000000000000fc]
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Stack slot to memory mapping:

stack at sp + 0 slots: 0x00007f6994387480 points into unknown readable memory: 0x00007f690c0dc201 | 01 c2 0d 0c 69 7f 00 00

stack at sp + 1 slots: 0x00007f6994391190 points into unknown readable memory: 0x00007f699438e830 | 30 e8 38 94 69 7f 00 00

stack at sp + 2 slots: 0x0000000000000384 is an unknown value

stack at sp + 3 slots: 0x00007f6994306870 points into unknown readable memory: 0x00007f6994387480 | 80 74 38 94 69 7f 00 00

stack at sp + 4 slots: 0x00007f68fc11f510 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000000261e800

stack at sp + 5 slots: 0x00007f6998e9d9aa: <offset 0x0000000000b379aa> in /usr/local/android-studio/jre/lib/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007f6998366000

stack at sp + 6 slots: 0x00007f6994306840 points into unknown readable memory: 0x00007f6900000000 | 00 00 00 00 69 7f 00 00

stack at sp + 7 slots: 0x0 is NULL

Comment: Please try this: `sudo downgrade jre11-openjdk jdk11-openjdk jre11-openjdk-headless` https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=262547, search for "leo2501"

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest Java version and compile using that. (Currently it is JDK 17).  Post the full error log if the issue persists. Another solution might be to set an environment property named `LD_BIND_NOW` to 1

Using bash, you can do it in this way

`$ export LD_BIND_NOW=1`

Link for downloading:

Windows x64:
https://download.oracle.com/java/17/latest/jdk-17_windows-x64_bin.exe

Linux x64:
https://download.oracle.com/java/17/latest/jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

MacOS:
https://download.oracle.com/java/17/latest/jdk-17_macos-aarch64_bin.dmg

Comment: I've already updated my Java version but it gives the same error.

Comment: I've added the firsts lines of the full log in the question.

Comment: Did some changes to the answer, try now.